# SQL запрос на выборку. Выборка из календаря

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, помогите новичку.

Есть таблица MySQL со столбцами EventID | Start | End

Start и End это тип datetime: начало и конец события.

Есть дата, например текущая. 
Как выглядит SQL-запрос, если нужно вытащить записи, которые пересекаются с определенной датой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот запрос выберет записи в интервал дат которых попадает текущая дата

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Comment: @SiDquakers, тогда попробуйте с `<=`/`>=`

Comment: Все отлично работает. @SiD quakers будь внимательней)

Comment: Да я вроде внимателен -). @Vincent Выборка не сработает, если Start 2018-12-24 00:00:00 и End 2018-12-24 00:00:00

Comment: почему она должна сработать если start = end?

Comment: А в случаи, если определенная дата, то как выглядит запрос?

Comment: Событие может происходить в течении одного дня и в таблице это указывается как Start = End